# SQLAlchemy - pretty print SQL query results

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, ipython, flask-sqlalchemy

In Ruby console, it is possible to display SQL query results in a very human-friendly way (ActiveRecord + Hirb):

```
>> Tag.all :limit=>3, :order=>"id DESC"
+-----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| id  | created_at              | description | name              | namespace | predicate | value    |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 907 | 2009-03-06 21:10:41 UTC |             | gem:tags=yaml     | gem       | tags      | yaml     |
| 906 | 2009-03-06 08:47:04 UTC |             | gem:tags=nomonkey | gem       | tags      | nomonkey |
| 905 | 2009-03-04 00:30:10 UTC |             | article:tags=ruby | article   | tags      | ruby     |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
3 rows in set
```

Is there a module that will allow me to do display SQLAlchemy result sets in a similar way in IPython?

Comment: I'd like to point out, that while this could be helpful, it seems like you maybe aren't not using ORM in the right way. You shouldn't think in terms of tables, but in terms of objects (generally). Write a decent repr function to your objects and you would have nice view of what you've actually loaded. You can even automatically print your objects as json for example. And if you're loading only exact columns you want, than you'll get namedtuple back and it's printed nicely also.